# Looking for example of using same partial view multiple times on a webpage

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Using .NET MVC, I have a partial view of an address that I need to implement multiple times on the same page because the user might have different types of addresses.  Being new to .NET MVC, I would like to find an example that would guide me through all the steps necessary.

Here is some of the code.  This first part of the code is the main page that includes the partial view.  I knew it was the wrong thing to do, but I first tried just listing the "Html.RenderPartial" line twice (for 2 different addresses).  I did that just to see what it would do.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<JCIMS_MVC2_EF.DomainModel.Data.Models.DistrictAddressModel>" %>


<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
Create District 
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<% Html.RenderPartial("DistrictHeaderPartial", this.ViewData.Model.DistrictHeader); %>   

<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>

<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>

    <fieldset id="address">
    <legend>Create new Address for <%: Model.DistrictHeader.District_Name %></legend>

        <% Html.RenderPartial("AddressEditPartial", this.Model); %>

    </fieldset>
    <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>


<% } %>

<div>
    <%: Html.ActionLink("Return to District Info Page", "Index", "District", new { id = Model.DistrictHeader.District_GUID }, null)%>
</div>

</asp:Content>
```

---

This is the partial view:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<JCIMS_MVC2_EF.DomainModel.Data.Models.BaseAddressModel>" %>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#AddressViewData_Zip_Code").mask("99999");
    });
</script>

<div class="editor-label">
<%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.AddressViewData.Address_Type_Text) %>    
</div>
<%: Html.DropDownList("AddressViewData.Address_Type_Code")%>
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AddressViewData.Address_Type_Code) %>
<div class="editor-label">
<%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.AddressViewData.Street_Address)%>
</div>                        
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AddressViewData.Street_Address, new { @class = "input-size" })%>
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AddressViewData.Street_Address) %>
<div class="editor-label">
<%: Html.Label("City") %>
</div>
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AddressViewData.City, new { @class = "input-size" })%>
<div class="editor-label">
<%: Html.Label("State") %>
</div>
<%: Html.DropDownList("AddressViewData.State")%>
<div class="editor-label">
<%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.AddressViewData.Zip_Code) %>
</div>
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AddressViewData.Zip_Code) %>
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AddressViewData.Zip_Code) %>
<div class="editor-label">
<%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.AddressViewData.Address_ATTN) %>
</div>
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AddressViewData.Address_ATTN, new { @class = "input-size" })%>
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AddressViewData.Address_ATTN) %>
```

Comment: Where in your view are you trying to render two different addresses? I can only see one `RenderPartial` related to your main view model... Maybe you're not explaining things clearly because I don't really understand what seems to be the problem here.

Comment: I tried adding the line: <% Html.RenderPartial("AddressEditPartial", this.Model); %> twice.  That's how I was trying to add 2 different addresses, but that didn't work correctly.

Answer (score 6):

Whats wrong with:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("Name", model ) %>
<% Html.RenderPartial("Name", differentModel ) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure what you need. But if I understand you correctly you have a property of type `List<Address>` in your model. If the problem seems to be getting this kind of data from the client to the server, then read [this blog post](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/09/preparing-list-of-objects-so-they-can.html) that will help you out.

If the problem is with displaying different addresses in a parent view it's just a simple `foreach` statement:

```
<% foreach(Address a in this.Model.Addresses) %>
<% { %>
    <% Html.RenderPartial("Address", a); %>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I may be unclear as to what you're looking for but basically you're situation is that you have a list of users each of which has a list of addresses.  So you'll iterate through your list of users and for each user their list of addresses like so (this code snippet is an example of c sharp embedded in an aspx page:

```
<% foreach(User lvUser in Model.Users)
{ %>
    <% Html.Encode(lvUser.Username) %>
    <% Html.Encode(lvUser.Email) %>

    <% foreach(Address lvAddress in lvUser.Addresses)
    { %>
       <% Html.RenderPartial("PartialAddress", lvAddress); %> //Where you've set the view data class to Address
    <% } %>


<% } %>
```